# What is the lidR filter_poi() equivalent to readLAS(..., "-keep_last")?

Tags: r, filter, las, lidr

With the excellent lidR package we can filter at C++ level when using `readLAS()`, e.g. with the following syntax

```
lidar = readLAS(LASfile, filter="-keep_first")
```

or when the pointcloud is already loaded at the R level, where above filter would translate to:

```
lidar_first = filter_poi(lidar, ReturnNumber == 1L)
```

Now I am wondering: What is the equivalent to `keep_last`?

It would be nice having a full list of attributes I could filter on. The doc elaborates on (LAStools/C++) options at the `readLAS` function (respectively one can list these with `readLAS(filter = "-help")`), but I haven't found a list of the R equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little trial and error, I found that this works:

```
lidar_first = filter_poi(lidar, ReturnNumber == NumberOfReturns)
```

The list of potential select attributes for `readLAS` in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf) gave me the hint that there might be a variable `NumberOfReturns` available (there it is called r - number of returns). However I haven't found any explicit hints on that anywhere.

A comprehensive list of filter options for `readLAS()` / `opt_filter()` can be found by running `readLAS(filter = "-help")`

Comment: `help("LAS-class")`  + https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAS-class.html +

Comment: that is a great help, thank you!

Comment: By the way do you know that there is `filter_first()` and `filter_last()` in lidR?